# Imagick fails to get pdf

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I have this part of code :

```
$im = new Imagick( $pdf_file );
            $im->setImageFormat( "png" );
            $im->scaleImage( 100, 100, true );
```

but i get the following error: `unable to open image` on `Imagick->__construct('/home/server/...')`

The pdf file is 8MB in size, but if i put a pdf that has 3 or 4 MB in size it works. Is there a way to make `Imagick` to take files with bigger size?

Thank you.

Comment: is the file readable? and if you run it from the imagick `convert` command line utility does it work?

Comment: The file is readable. I am not allowed to use the command line to generate the thumb from pdf file.

Comment: do you mean you have no shell access on the web server? ask someone with shell access to test it for you

Comment: i`ve tried on shell with command line and it works but on php script doesn`t. I can`t figure it out.

Comment: make sure the file permissions are 777 (`chmod 777 filename.pdf`) and try via php again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be your `memory_limit` is lower than 8MB.  Check it with

`var_dump(ini_get('memory_limit'));`

You'll also be able to set this outside of php.ini

`ini_set('memory_limit', '8M');`

Comment: it was set to 5MB. Thanks a lot